# How to create a surface from a raster which goes through all the local maximum altitudes of my raster using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, surface, maximum

I am struggling to create a surface from a raster using QGIS. The surface needs to go through all local maximum altitudes of my raster (tangent to vertices) and needs to have some kind of smoothed concave aspect (I don't want to get a linear smoothed surface).

To better understand, I used the profile tool of QGIS and I obtained a profile of a hill (altitudes versus distance).

In green is the profile of the hill with a lot of small local variations (caused by erosion) that I have (slope goes between 10 to 30%):

[image: What I have]

I would like to obtain another raster that would be a surface going through all the maximum local vertices of the hill with some kind of smoothed concave aspect like the one in yellow:

[image: In yellow What I would like]

The created surface would be like a surface that covers all the holes caused by erosion.
I will then perform a volume comparison between the two to estimate and calculate the erosion volume loss.

Does someone have an idea on how I could do that on QGIS?

I tried interpolation but I got a median or mean profile that does not go through all the vertices (local maximum altitudes).

Comment: Have you tried r.neighbors in QGIS (GRASS raster toolbox) or Focal Statistics (Spatial Analyst  toolbox) in ArcGIS with the maximum statistic?

Comment: Please decide which of QGIS GUI, PyQGIS or Python you wish to ask about in this particular question.